# INDEX/Match and VLOOKUP Assistance

Tags: excel

So, I have a table, that looks like the following:

[image: table]

What I want to do:
Return the name of the person who has the orange block for the current day.

What I can do: 
    `=MATCH(EDATE(NOW(), 0), B9:AQ9,0)`

Which, since today is the 16th, returns Column 18.

So, I'd want to search for any orange block in column 18. An orange block is orange because it has the text `x` in it.

Only, I do not know how to search with just that column only.

Once I get the row number of that column, I'll then need to be able to return an `INDEX()` lookup of the COLUMN and ROW in the first column `A` to return the name of the person.

Name column is Column A - and the last column in that list is AQ.

The row `B9:AQ9` is where the day numbers are; these are actually dates, just formatted only to return the `day` portion.

So, I know how to find the column in question, that's with the code above. I'm just not sure how to REFERENCE that column and match any "x" in that column to return the ROW.

In this case, for 1/16/2019 (the yellow highlighted column there), it would return `Krystle`, as the lookup should return Column 18, Row 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `MATCH` formula you provided, you can get the column corresponding to that date (as an array) using this formula:

```
=INDEX($B$10:$AQ$13, , MATCH(EDATE(NOW(), 0), $B$9:$AQ$9, 0))
```

Then you can `MATCH` a name based on the values in that array:

```
=INDEX($A$10:$A$13, MATCH("x", INDEX($B$10:$AQ$13, , MATCH(EDATE(NOW(), 0), $B$9:$AQ$9, 0)), 0))
```

Comment: Ah, that's how that is used. Thank you! That really clarifies the situation there. I thought I was going crazy lol

Comment: Nice approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your column 18 is column T for the following,

Based on what you say, this looks for an "x" in col T and returns the name from Col A in the same position:

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,match("x",T2:T5,0))
```

An example, using different columns:
[image]

Comment: So, I changed the image, so you can see the row and column numbers as well. Should have included that to begin with. The main issue here is that I don't know What column it would be, as each day it would be a different column, and each day it'd be a different row. Not sure if I'm explaining that well enough lol